# How to solve ValueError while iterating and appending to list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested-loops, valueerror

ValueError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 4 columns:

```
import pandas as pd    
def customedata():
    colnum = input("How many columns do you need? ")
    colnum = int(colnum)
    rownum = input("How many rows do you need? ")
    # user input column and row
    rownum = int(rownum)
    colName = []
    rowName = []
     # create an empty list

    for col in range(0,colnum):
           colValue =input('Enter the value for column name of column %s:' %(col + 1))
           colName.append(colValue)
           for row in range(0,rownum):
                  rowValue = (int(input('Enter the value of row number %s:' %(row + 1))))
                  rowName.append(rowValue)
                  row = row + 1
                  col = col + 1
    # columns = colName[i]
    df1= pd.DataFrame([rowName],columns = colName)
    print(df1)
```

I tried to create a dataframe using user input rows and columns but I keep getting valueError. I tought that it had something wrong with the nested loop but I wasn't able to solve the problem.

Comment: I think you should remove the `row = row + 1` and `col = col + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be easier to create a `pd.DataFrame` from user input using a dictionary like below. First you create an empty `dict`, then you pass the `colName` as key and your `rowName`list as value. Then you can use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()` to transform your dict to a `pd.DataFrame`

Hoping it helps :)

```
def customedata():
    colnum = input("How many columns do you need? ")
    colnum = int(colnum)
    rownum = input("How many rows do you need? ")
    # user input column and row
    rownum = int(rownum)
    colName = []
    rowName = []
    dictionary = {}
    for col in range(0, colnum):
        colValue = input('Enter the value for column name of column %s:' % (col + 1))
        for row in range(0, rownum):
            rowValue = (int(input('Enter the value of row number %s:' % (row + 1))))
            rowName.append(rowValue)
        dictionary[colValue] = rowName
    df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary)
    print(df1)
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)